# Change Adjacent Cell Vlaue Based on Cell Fill Color When Cell Color Changes VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how I can add some code to my worksheet in VBA that evaluates a cell color only when the color is changed? So it would be similar to something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then

Call Search_Batch_Docs

End If

End Sub
```

But would only trigger on a fill color change.

I have a sheet where I have color coded a column but I also have a column that contains a specific word that coincides with the color of the first column.

Comment: Is the cell color being changed due to conditional formatting?  If so use the rule for that as your test instead of the color. If not then you will need to use a sub routine that is called manually as there is no event that will capture the change of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't have an event specifically for background color change.  But checking the color of a single cell with each change shouldn't be unreasonable for most use-cases.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.Interior.color <> xlNone Then

Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case 3
        Target.offset(0, 1).Value = "Text if adjacent cell is red"
    'And so on

End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: As per the comments below, this assumes that a VALUE in the targeted range has been changed, not only the formatting.  If you require an event-based solution that is called more frequently, you could try `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to be called every time a new range becomes the active selection, but it will be less efficient.

If possible, it might be best to have a button to update values when pressed.  And/or have it update when the worksheet is activated using `Worksheet_Activate`.

Comment: This will require that the value in B1 change.  This will not fire if only the formatting is changed.

Comment: This is true.  I suppose I assumed that the color change was associated with a change in value.  There is no event in Excel that is triggered only by format change, so the only other possible VBA-based option (that I can think of) is Worksheet_SelectionChange, which would obviously check when the selected range changes.  Not efficient, but perhaps the only VBA event-based solution.  It might be best to simply have a button to update the values when pressed, if that's acceptable.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that it would check the active cell upon that cell's selection and then based on the color, make the appropriate change to a adjacent cell?

Comment: If you use Worksheet_SelectionChange, yes, that is what it would do.  The problem with this is that if you select the cell and change the color, it won't update the adjacent cell until you re-select the cell again.  One way around this is to use a sheet-scoped variable to remember the last-selected cell (assign it to Target at the end of your function), essentially letting you know what cell was just de-selected.  If it's one of your target cells, you can update the value on de-select.